# Android custom ListView: adding search function

Tags: android, listview, search, android-edittext

i've a problem, i want an EditText above my ListView that performs a search in that ListView. Is it possible to do?

This is the Activity code:

```
public static class BirreChiareListView extends Main implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView list;
    String [] birrechiare;
    int [] images={R.drawable.ichnusa, R.drawable.ichnusa_speciale, R.drawable.ichnusa_cruda};
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(birrechiare_listview);

        Resources res=getResources();
        birrechiare=res.getStringArray(R.array.birre_chiare);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewBirreChiare);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,birrechiare, images);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long l) {
        String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hai selezionato: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (position == 0){
            Intent gotoclassica = new Intent(BirreChiareListView.this,Ichnusa_Classica.class);
            startActivity(gotoclassica);
        }
        if (position == 1){
            Intent gotospeciale = new Intent(BirreChiareListView.this,Ichnusa_Speciale.class);
            startActivity(gotospeciale);
        }
        if (position == 2){
            Intent gotocruda = new Intent(BirreChiareListView.this,Ichnusa_Cruda.class);
            startActivity(gotocruda);
        }
    }
}

static class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] titleArray;

    MyAdapter(Context c, String[] titles, int imgs []){
        super (c, single_row, R.id.Titletxt, titles);
        this.context = c;
        this.images=imgs;
        this.titleArray=titles;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(single_row, parent,false);
        ImageView myimage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView mytitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Titletxt);
        myimage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        mytitle.setText(titleArray[position]);

        return row;

    }
}
```

Ok, this is the XML file of the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background_listview">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Birre Chiare"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewBirreChiare"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

At the end, this is the single_row.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ichnusa"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/Titletxt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible to do. Android provides a `Filterable` interface for `ArrayAdapter`s. The interface provides a `getFilter()` method where you can hook into the filtering process.

When the text changes in your `EditText`, you call `adapter.getFilter().filter("filterString")`. The text changing behaviour for the `EditText` is done by using a `TextWatcher` on the `EditText`. This following tutorial, explains it in good detail:

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

EDIT:

To implement the filterable interface, just do this in your `ArrayAdapter`:

```
static class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private Filter myFilter;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (myFilter == null)
            myFilter = new MyFilter();

        return myFilter;
    }
}
```

where `MyFilter` is your own `Filter` class.

Comment: Read the tutorial thoroughly please. Did you implement the `Filterable` interface in your ArrayAdapter? If so, post the code in a edit and let me know with a comment.

Comment: I can't implement the Filterable interface in my Adapter. I don't know where tu put it in my code.

Comment: @invisible142 StackOverflow can't explain the basics of everything, I'm sorry. You should definitely read up on Java interfaces. You can't just jump into Android development, or you'll run into these Java things. I will, however, show you how you implement it in my edit.

Comment: the code seems to work but when I write any letter it always shows the same three results, but in my list there are about ten..really don't know why!